# Get card data object in card Buttontheme bar

Tags: dart, flutter

Good morning,
I'm new on Flutter.
I need to open a new page from a card after a button press. To open the new page I need the card data object that I use to show the information (data[X]). The button for open the new page is located in ButtonTheme.bar but in this location I don't have my "data[X]" object.

This is my code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Records Page", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(32, 38, 48, 1),
    ),
    drawer: MainDrawer(),
    body: new ListView.builder(
      //reverse: true,
        itemCount: reversedData != null ? reversedData.length : 0,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          if (reversedData[index].stop != null) {
            return Card(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                    title: Text('Last Period'),
                    //subtitle: Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    child: new ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Text(
                            "Hour: ${reversedData[index].hourType.description}"),
                        new Text("Job: ${reversedData[index].job.description}"),
                        new Text(
                            "Opened at: ${DateFormat.yMd().add_jm().format(DateTime.parse(reversedData[index].start))}"),
                        new Text(
                            "Closed at: ${DateFormat.yMd().add_jm().format(DateTime.parse(reversedData[index].stop))}"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  ButtonTheme.bar(
                    // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
                    child: ButtonBar(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                          child: const Text('Modify',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(32, 38, 48, 1))),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (__) => new PeriodEditPage(toChangeData: //my card data? ,)));
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }));
```

}

I simply need to have the specific card data when I'm going to open the new page.
Hope I was clear.
Thank you

Comment: I didn't get what's your card data

Comment: Please refert to the other comment. Here I explain better my problem

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to declare your data in your `statefulWidget` (or `statelessWidget`) then use then wherever you want.

You can also create an object `data` where you'll have all your information instanciate one into your widget then pass it to another screen.

Here's an intro about passing data : https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: Mi problem isn’t pass data between Pages because I haven’t the data to pass. in my case there is a listview builder that produce as many cards as there are object in the “reverseData” List. Every card has a “modify” button, when I press the modify button I need to have the specific reverseData object that I use to show the card information. For example if the first card is made with reverseData[0], when I presa modify button I need to have reverseData[0] object to pass to my new page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution to my problem:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Records Page", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      iconTheme: new IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(32, 38, 48, 1),
    ),
    drawer: MainDrawer(),
    body: new ListView.builder(
        //reverse: true,
        itemCount: reversedData != null ? reversedData.length : 0,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          if (reversedData[index].stop != null) {
            return Card(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  const ListTile(
                    leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                    title: Text('Last Period'),
                    //subtitle: Text('Music by Julie Gable. Lyrics by Sidney Stein.'),
                  ),
                  new Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                    child: new ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Text(
                            "Hour: ${reversedData[index].hourType.description}"),
                        new Text(
                            "Job: ${reversedData[index].job.description}"),
                        new Text(
                            "Opened at: ${DateFormat.yMd().add_jm().format(DateTime.parse(reversedData[index].start))}"),
                        new Text(
                            "Closed at: ${DateFormat.yMd().add_jm().format(DateTime.parse(reversedData[index].stop))}"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  ButtonTheme.bar(
                    // make buttons use the appropriate styles for cards
                    child: ButtonBar(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FlatButton(
                          child: const Text('Modify',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(32, 38, 48, 1))),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                new MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (__) => new PeriodEditPage(
                                          toChangeData: reversedData[index],
                                        )));
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }));
```

}

My problem was solved thank to this line:

```
toChangeData: reversedData[index],
```

This code permit to open every card details with the same object used to populate my card.

I haven't understand properly what happen with the object reference but it works for me.